# If the Fourier serie $S_nf\longrightarrow g$ in $L^p$ then $f=g$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose that $f\in L^1(\mathbb S^1)$ where $\mathbb S^1=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. Suppose that the sequence of partial Fourier sums $\{S_nf\}_{n\geq 1}$ converge in $L^p(\mathbb S^1)$ toward some $g\in L^p(\mathbb S^1)$ (here $p\in [1,\infty ]$). Show that $f=g$.

**My work**

If $\{S_nf\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge do we necessarily have $S_nf$ converge also to $f$ ? If yes, the result is obvious, but it's may be what I have to show. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing is probably to show that $\hat f(n)=\hat g(n)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not conclusive.

Comment: Huh??????????????

Comment: I probably miss something, but $\hat f(n)=\int_0^1 f(x)e^{-2i\pi x}dx$ and $\hat g(n)=\int_0^1 g(x)e^{-2\pi inx}dx$. Now what I know is $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int _0^1 \left|\sum_{N\leq |n|}\hat f(n)e^{2\pi nx}-g(x)\right|^p=0.$$ Now, how you get $\hat f(n)=\hat g(n)$ ? I have big formula that I can't reduce...

Comment: @user301068 Holder's inequality shows that $|\widehat{g-S_nf}(k)|\le ||g-S_nf||_p$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how. To me, Holder says $\|fg\|_1\leq \|f\|_p\|g\|_q$ when $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$

Comment: @user301068 Yes, that's Holder's inequality. Now write down the definition of $\widehat{g-S_nf}(k)$ as an integral and apply Holder to that integral. (Here $\widehat{g-S_nf}(k)$ is the $k$th Fourier coefficient of $g-S_nf$.)

Comment: Last thing, and then I'll give you the bounty :-) So we get $$\hat g(k)=\int_0^1\sum_{n=-\infty }^\infty \hat f(n) e^{2i \pi(k-n)x}dx.$$ How can I permute the sum and the integral to get $\hat f(k)=\hat g(k)$ ? Because the convergence is not uniform, it is ? Finally, did we show the result for all $p$ or we have to do the case $p=\infty $ ?

Comment: @user301068 I don't see how we get what you said we get. And that's not what I was suggesting. Let's say $E_n=g-S_nf$ to make things easier to read and write. Then $|\hat E_n(k)|=|\int_0^1e^{-2\pi ikt}E_n(t)|\le||e^{-2\pi ikt}||_q||E_n||_p=||E_n||_p\to 0.$ So $\hat g(k)=\lim_n\widehat{S_n}(k)$. But $\widehat{S_n}(k)=\hat f(k)$ for $n>|k|$. So $\hat g(k)=\hat f(k)$.

Comment: Great, I'll give my my bounty when I'll can. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, are you at EPFL ? If yes, normally we were supposed to do this exercise by ourselves. Anyway have a good day !

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it, but with probably more material required :

Define the Fejér means : $$\sigma_n(f)=\frac{1}{n+1}(S_0(f)+\ldots+S_n(f)),$$
one know that $\sigma_n(f)$ converge to $f$ almost everywhere (theorem page 20 of *introduction to harmonic analysis* third edition by Y. Katznelson). But since $S_n(f)$ is converging to $g$ in $L^p$ one also has that $\sigma_n(f)$ is converging to $g$ in $L^p$. Now, up to a sub sequence, $\sigma_n(f)$ converge almost everywhere to g and also to f, and thus we get $f=g$.

Comment: Actually very close to the same as what I said, just writing out different aspects of it explicitly - certainly requires more or less the same background: In my answer I imply that it's easy to show that $\hat f(k)=\hat g(k)$, and then it follows that $f=g$. _Showing_ that $f=g$ follows is going to be by some argument using the Fejer kernel or some other approximate identity,..

Comment: hum are you sure ? i didn't read through all the comments of your answer but the convergence almost everywhere of he Fejér means seems (to me) different from $\hat f = \hat g \Rightarrow f=g$, but maybe i'm wrong !

Comment: Well how do _you_ show that $\hat f=\hat g$ implies $f=g$? (Note I didn't mean my comment as a criticism, just a comment...)

Comment: hum ok, i just thought there was an easier way to show that implication.

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim_n\|S_n f - g\|_{L^p}=0$ for some $g \in L^p$ with $p\in [1,\infty)$, then, for $n \ge |k|$ and for $q \in (1,\infty]$ conjugate to $p$,
\begin{align}
         |\hat{f}(k)-\hat{g}(k)| & =|\widehat{(S_n f)}(k)-\widehat{g}(k)| \\
      & \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|S_nf-g|dx \\
      & \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\|S_n f-g\|_p\|1\|_q \rightarrow 0 \mbox{ as }n\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}
So it is definitely true that $\hat{f}(k)=\hat{g}(k)$ for all $k$. Both $f$ and $g$ are in $L^1$. So the problem of showing that $f=g$ a.e. is reduced to looking at the uniqueness of Fourier coefficients for functions in $L^1$. Every $2\pi$ periodic continuously-differentiable function $h$ is the uniform limit of its Fourier series, which gives
$$
         \int_{0}^{2\pi}(f-g)hdx=\lim_{n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(f-g)S_{n}hdx =\lim_n 0=0.
$$
Using the bounded convergence theorem, you can obtain
$$
           0=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(f-g)\chi_{[0,t]}dx=\int_{0}^{t}(f-g)dx.
$$
By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem,
$$
            0=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t}(f-g)dx = f(t)-g(t) \;\;\; a.e. t\in [0,2\pi].
$$
Hence, $f=g$ a.e..